# SQL Query Issue - Natural Join and table naming

Tags: sql, join, natural-join

I'm running into some difficulty with a query for my databases class. Given the following schema:

- Customers (`customerid, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, phone, status`)
- Branches (`branchno, address, city, state, phone, manager_name`)
- Employees (`empno, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, phone, emergency_contact, title, managerno`)
- Rooms (`roomno, branchno, price, bed_size`)
- Bookings (`roomno, branchno, customerid, checkin_date, checkout_date, empno`)

I'd like to find the customer(s) that have rented the most expensive room. I gave this query a try...

```
SELECT customerid FROM bookings NATURAL JOIN rooms 
EXCEPT
(SELECT customerid FROM (bookings NATURAL JOIN rooms) AS S, (bookings NATURAL JOIN
    rooms) as T WHERE S.price < T.price)
```

The problem comes from the way I want to rename the tables. I'd like to use the natural join of bookings and rooms as components of the Cartesian product... How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: **What** database system and **which version** are you using??

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
SELECT 
    customerid 
FROM 
    Bookings 
  NATURAL JOIN 
    Rooms
  NATURAL JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(price) AS price
      FROM Rooms
    ) AS MostExpensiveRoom
```

---

Your query seems valid, except that you need to clarify which `customerid` you want in the second subquery, the `S.` or the `T.` one. The comma `,` syntax means a `CROSS JOIN` between `S` and `T` so you have two customerids:

```
(SELECT customerid FROM bookings NATURAL JOIN rooms)
EXCEPT
(SELECT S.customerid 
 FROM 
     (bookings NATURAL JOIN rooms) AS S
   CROSS JOIN
     (bookings NATURAL JOIN rooms) AS T 
 WHERE S.price < T.price
)
```

Comment: @Maestro1 But comma *means* cross join. (With lower precedence than explicit joins.) If you want to "use natural join" then you want something like `select customerid from (select price as ps from (...) s) natural join (..) t where ps < price)`. Algebras with headings that are column sets have "cross join" that is natural join with no shared columns, and algebras with headings that are column lists hack "natural join". SQL natural join means inner join using (shared columns) with no dotting shared columns. Or consider natural join to be select * from left natural join right.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM customers as c
INNER JOIN bookings as b ON b.customerid = c.customerid
INNER JOIN rooms as r ON r.roomno = b.roomno
ORDER BY r.price DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

if you want only the names, or specified fields, you can use GROUP BY.

This query do the same (if the previous is good syntactically):

```
SELECT * FROM customers,bookings,rooms
WHERE bookings.customerid = customers.customerid
AND rooms.roomno = bookings.roomno
ORDER BY rooms.price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

so if you want id-s and names ordered by rent price desc:

```
SELECT customers.customerid, customers.fistname, customers.lastname FROM
customers,bookings,rooms
WHERE bookings.customerid = customers.customerid
AND rooms.roomno = bookings.roomno
ORDER BY rooms.price DESC
GROUP BY customers.customerid, customers.fistname, customers.lastname 
LIMIT 10
```